# Function definition in Inheritance

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, definition

When publicly inheriting a class, why can't I define a function of the base class using name of derived class if the public members of base class are inherited by that derived class?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class one{
    int a;
public:
    void get(int);
    void show();
};

class two:public one
{
    int b;
public:
    void getb(int);
    void dis();
};

void one::get(int x)  //if i write void two::get(int x) here it gives error
{
    a = x;
}
void one::show()  //same goes for this function why can't i define it as `void two::show()`?
{
  cout << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
    two ob;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    ob.get( x );
    ob.show();
}
```

So if if all public member functions of class `one` are inherited by class `two`, why can't I define functions of class `one` using name of class `two` ?

Comment: Because `class one` is not an abstract class - if you instantiate a new instance of `one` what implementation should it use?

Comment: because `a` is `private` member of class `one` and thus cannot be accessed outside class `one`. Or your question is not clear... What error did you had?

Comment: did you try `override` it ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Why ?

In the class definition, you say that `two` inherits from `one`.  So it will have the following public members:

```
void get(int);       publicly inherited from one
void show();         publicly inherited from one
void getb(int);      own member
void dis();          own member
```

You can define only the own member functions of `two`, here `two::getb(int)` and `two::dis()`.  But you can't define `two::show()` because it was defined in one and you did not tell the compiler that you wanted it.

#### Is there a way to do have a different version of the inherited functions ?

If you'd define the class as follows:

```
class two:public one
{
    int b;
public:
    void getb(int);
    void dis();
    void show();     //yes you can, but you'll have to define it 
};
```

then you would have the following public members:

```
void get(int);       publicly inherited from one
void one::show();    publicly inherited from one but hidden 
void show();         own member
void getb(int);      own member
void dis();          own member
```

you could define the following:

```
void two::show()  //no problem !!
{
  cout << "two's version" << endl;
}
```

You could even choose in `main()` which one you want to call:

```
ob.get( x );          // one::get(), because there's no two::get()
ob.show();            // by default two::show(), because ob is a two
ob.one::show();       // yes you can !!
```

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/UwGl2Q)

#### Want polymorphism ?

In all the code above, the function invoked depend on the type used to access the object:

```
one *pob = &ob;  // a one pointer can point to a two object 
pob->show();     // but this will invoke one::show()
```

If you'd prefer the right function be called depending on the real type of the object, and not the type assumed from the type declaration, you'd need to use virtual functions and override them:

```
class one{
    ... (the rest as before) ...
    virtual void show();
};

class two:public one
{
    ... (the rest as before) ...
    void show() override;  
};
```

Then, whenever you invoke `show()`, the correct function will be called ([online example](https://ideone.com/lVCObN)), unless you specifically inkove a precisely specified version by using a fully qualified identifier.